# PHP Curl process hitting a timeout when using Squid Proxy

Tags: php, squid, curl

I have a PHP process that running a CURL command to get the contents of a website. This works on 90% of websites that I try it on but one site in particular (the one I want to get the contents of) hits a timeout whenever I CURL it - 120 seconds... I thought it could be a region block so I set a Squid Proxy server in a different state but still hitting the error. Any other thoughts on things I can try or check? I am stumped!

Thank you

Comment: Is the web site up?

Comment: Yes - I confirmed the destination website is up (I can view it on my local client directly) and that the proxy server is up (works for other websites).